# How do you find the Fourier coefficients of $f(3x)$ with given Fourier-series of $f(x)$!

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Given that $f(x)$ has period $2\pi$ and is represented by a Fourier-series $$f(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{n = 0}a_n\cos(nx) + b_n\sin(nx)$$

what are then the Fourier coefficients, if using the same period $2\pi$, for the function $f(3x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ g(x) = f(3x) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n\cos(3nx)+b_n\sin(3nx) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}c_n\cos(nx)+d_n\sin(nx)$$

where $$
c_n = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        a_n & \mbox{if } n \equiv 0[3] \\
        0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

and $$
d_n = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        b_n & \mbox{if } n \equiv 0[3] \\
        0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Given that $f(x)$ has period $2\pi$ and is represented by a Fourier-series $$f(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{n = 0}a_n\cos(nx) + b_n\sin(nx)$$
$g(x)=f(3x)$ has period $T= \frac{2\pi}{3}$ and is represented by a Fourier-series

$$f(x) =a_0(g)+ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left ( a_n (g) \cdot \cos \left ( nx\frac{2\pi}{T} \right ) +  b_n(g) \cdot \sin \left ( nx\frac{2\pi}{T} \right )\right )\\ 
=a_0(g)+ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left ( a_n (g) \cdot \cos \left ( 3nx \right ) +  b_n(g) \cdot \sin \left ( 3 nx \right )\right ).$$
but, 
$$f(3x) = \sum^{\infty}_{n = 0}a_n\cos(3nx) + b_n\sin(3nx)$$ hence buy identification, $a_n = a_n(g) $ and $b_n = b_n(g)$ if $n=3p$  and $a_n = b_n = 0$ otherwise.